# Why LATERAL not works with values?

Tags: postgresql, expression, lateral

It not make sense, a literal is not a valid column?

```sql
SELECT x, y FROM (select 1 as x) t, LATERAL CAST(2 AS FLOAT) AS y; -- fine
SELECT x, y FROM (select 1 as x) t, LATERAL 2.0 AS y; -- SYNNTAX ERROR!
```

Same if you use `CASE` clause or `x+1` expression or `(x+1)`... seems ERROR for any non-function.

The [Pg Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html), about `LATERAL expression` (not LATERAL subquery), say

> LATERAL is primarily useful when the cross-referenced column is necessary for computing the row(s) to be joined (...)

---

#### NOTES

The question is about `LATERAL 1_column_expression` not `LATERAL multicolumn_subquery`.  Example:

```
SELECT x, y, exp, z
FROM (select 3) t(x), -- subquery
     LATERAL round(x*0.2+1.2) as exp,  -- expression!
     LATERAL (SELECT exp+2.0 AS y, x||'foo' as z) t2  --subquery
;
```

... After @klin comment showing that [the Guide in another point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) say "only functions", the question  *Why?*  must be expressed in a more specific way, changing a litle bit the scope of the question:

Not make sense "only funcions", the syntax `(x)` or `(x+1)`, encapsulatening expression in parentesis, is fine, is not?
**Why only functions?**

PS: perhaps there is a future plan, or perhaps a real problem on parsing generic expressions...  As users we must show to PostgreSQL developers what make sense and we need.

Comment: According to [SELECT syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) there may be a subquery or a function after LATERAL.

Comment: @klin you show that there is a *spec constraint*, thanks (!)... Well, maybe changing a litle bit the question, **why only functions?**  What the problem with `(x)`  or `(x+1)` using parentesis?

Comment: Why? Standard SQL requires a subquery. A function call in this context is a Postgres extension, very handy IMO.

Comment: From a practical point of view, I don't remember needing an expression in LATERAL, while I use functions regularly (typically set-returning functions).

Answer (score 0):

It'll all work fine if you wrap it in its own subquery

```sql
SELECT x, y FROM (select 1 as x) t, LATERAL (SELECT 2.0 AS y) z;
```

Comment: But why the syntax `LATERAL f(x) AS y`  is valid and `LATERAL x AS y` is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

A literal is a valid value for a column, but as the docs you quoted say, `LATERAL` syntax is used

> for computing the **row(s)** to be joined

A relation, such as a `FROM` or `JOIN` or `LATERAL` subquery clause, always computes tuples of (a single or multiple) columns. The alias you're assigning is not for an individual row, but for the whole tuple.

Comment: But "Why only functions?", the semantic of `CAST(2 AS int) AS y` and `2 AS y`  is the same, why the syntactic barrier?

Comment: I guess `LATERAL 2.0 AS y` could be interpreted as `LATERAL "2"."0" AS y` (i.e. table `0` from schema `2`). The parser just is written to only accept identifiers in that location, not arbitrary expressions, to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Answering **"Why only functions?"** by intuition.

---

Or "Why does **the PostgreSQL spec** use only functions?". Of course, it's not a question about the parser, because it complies with the specification.

The [`SELECT` syntax Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) show the only occasions when we can use `LATERAL`:

```
[ LATERAL ] ( select ) [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ] ...
[ LATERAL ] function_name ( [ argument [, ...] ] ) ...
[ LATERAL ] ROWS FROM( function_name ( [ argument [, ...] ] ) ...
```

So, no conflict on

```
[ LATERAL ] (single_expression) [ AS ] alias
```

The guess of  @Bergi is that a literal expression like `LATERAL 2.0 AS y`  could be interpreted as `LATERAL "2"."0"`, the "table 0" and  "schema 2"... But, as we saw above, not make sense to expect a table name after clause `LATERAL`, so, in fact, no ambiguity.

Conclusion: it looks like **the specification** of `LATERAL` can grow and allow the use of expressions.
This is the great advantage of being able to discuss and participate in an open community software!

---

*Why `LATERAL single_expression AS alias`?* Rationale:

- to be orthogonal: any new user of PostgreSQL, that see that is valid `SELECT a, x, x+b AS y FROM t, LATERAL f(a) AS x`, will naturally try also expressions instead functions. It is expected in a "orthogonal system" and is intuitive for any programmer.
- to reuse expressions: we use "chain of dependent expressions"  in any language, things like `a=b+c; x=a+y; z=a/2; ...`. It is ugly to do "SELECT(SELECT(SELECT))" in SQL, only for reuse expressions. The "chains of LATERALs" is more elegant and human-readable. 
  And perhaps is better also for query optimization.